# Error when play is clicked:NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am pretty new to C# and unity,so my question could be basic. However it has bugged me for so long, that I couldn't get it over even after I research it over the internet.

Anyway, here is my question, I have got this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object AchievementButton.click()(at
>   Assets/scripts/AchievementSystem/AchievementButton.cs:25)
>   AchievementManager.Start()(at
>   Assets/scripts/AchievementSystem/AchievementManager.cs:30)

when clicked on play or when click a button to view my list of achievements.

AchievementManager Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AchievemenetManager : MonoBehaviour
{


    public GameObject achievementPrefab;

    public Sprite[] sprites;

    public AchievementButton activeButton;


    public ScrollRect scrollRect;


    // Use this for initialization

    void Start ()
    { 
       //here is where the error is logged from
        activeButton = GameObject.Find("Streakbtn").GetComponent<AchievementButton>();
        CreateAchievement("Streak","testTitle","this is a description",3,0);

        activeButton.click();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void CreateAchievement(string category,string title,string description,int points, int spriteIndex)
    {
        GameObject achievement = (GameObject)Instantiate(achievementPrefab);
        SetAchievementInfo(category, achievement,title,description,points,spriteIndex);
    }

    public void SetAchievementInfo(string category, GameObject achievement, string title, string description, int points, int spriteIndex)
    {
        achievement.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find(category).transform);
        achievement.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        achievement.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        achievement.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = title;
        achievement.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>().text = description;
        achievement.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>().text = points.ToString();
        achievement.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprites[spriteIndex];
    }

   public void ChangeCategery(GameObject button)
    {
        AchievementButton achievementButton = button.GetComponent<AchievementButton>();

        scrollRect.content = achievementButton.achievementList.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        achievementButton.click();
        activeButton.click();

        activeButton = achievementButton;




    }

}
```

AchievementButton Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AchievementButton : MonoBehaviour 
{


    public GameObject achievementList;

    public Sprite neutral, highlight;

    private Image sprite;

    void awake()
    {
        sprite = GetComponent<Image>();

    }



    public void click()
    {
         //here is where the error is logged from

        if(sprite.sprite == neutral)
        {
            sprite.sprite = highlight;
            achievementList.SetActive(true);

        }

        else
        {
            sprite.sprite = neutral;
            achievementList.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Your `awake()` method starts with lowercase, while it should start with uppercase: `void Awake()`

Adjust your `Awake` method like this:

```
void Awake()
{
    sprite = GetComponent<Image>();
    Debug.Log("Awake has been called, sprite is " + sprite);
    Debug.Log("neutral is " + neutral);
    Debug.Log("highlight is " + highlight);
}
```

to see whether the method gets called at all and whether all three variables (`sprite`, `neutral`, `highlight`) are defined (they must not be `null`).

You can see the output of `Debug.Log()` in `Console`, which can be found in Unity when you click on menu item `View -> Console`. Use `Debug.Log()` frequently to see what's going on in your scripts.

If the `neutral` and `highlight` variables are `null` in the `Awake`, you need to assign them manually via Inspector, i.e. drag and drop some sprites to them to `AchievementButton` game object in the Editor.

Answer (score 0):

`NullReferenceException` occurs when you try to use a variable you haven't yet assigned to. <s>In this case i think it's `sprite.sprite` under your `click()` method. I would check to make sure your `awake()` method that gives sprite a value always runs before `click()`</s> You assign `neutral` or `highlight` to `sprite.sprite` before you give a value to either `neutral` or `highlight`.

```
neutral = ?? ;// something of type Sprite
highlight = ?? ;// something of type Sprite
```

Comment: @surajmaharaj okay thanks I'll remove that from my answer. Your problem is most likely related to sprite not being defined before your click() method.

Comment: @surajmaharaj If awake isn't called before click, sprite wont be defined. However, your use of neutral and highlight certainly are a problem.

Comment: You need to assign some value to `neutral` and `highlight` before you use them. I'm not sure what you want to use them for so I can't tell you what to define them as. You could do this in awake() or in click(), whichever  is appropriate for your design.

Comment: btw - checkout @Arx 's answer to make sure your awake method is actually being called.